# Best method for comment parent attachment?

Tags: php

What is the best way of have a recursive comments section, where comments are structured like so:

```
top level comment (parent:0, id:1)  
    reply comment (parent: 1, id: 2)  
        reply reply comment (parent: 2, id: 5)  
    reply comment (parent: 1, id: 4)  
top level comment (parent:0, id:3)  
top level comment (parent:0, id: 6)
```

I already have a method for replying to an existing comment, but I need a way to loop through each row in the database to create the structure above.

Comment: maybe you can implement everything in a single table. if you have a single table, you just need to set the parent_id to 0 for top level comments and the id of the comment or parent reply for the rest of replies... looking by parent_ids you will end with that structure you need...

Comment: Ryu, how would you create this structure purely by looking at the parents, I don't believe it's possible?

Comment: `comment (id, parent_id, post_id, message)` assuming id is autoincrement, when you post a top level comment, you set your post_id, and the message, parent_id should be 0... when you reply to a comment, you post a new comment from the same post_id, but now parent_id should be the id of the parent comment, and so on... when you have to render  this structure, first, you search from all the comments with a sset post_id but with parent_id = 0, now for each one, in a new query, search for all the comments with the parent_id = id of the comment you are searching, and again repeat that recursively..

Answer (score 1):

So, you store your comment data in a relational database where each comment has a parent id, then the simplest way to do it is with recursion. You can do a recursive function in PHP to query the database which incurs a lot of overhead, or you can write a recursive procedure in your database which will be a long running query on the database.

You could also restructure your data into the "nested set" structure (a good write up is here: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) and then you can retrieve the data without any recursion. However, inserts will be more costly.

Another solution is to abandon the relational model and use a document database which allows you store arbitrary hierarchies without multiple records. This is possible using databases like Postgresql, CouchDB, or MongoDB.

Without knowing which database system you're using, it's not possible to give you a perfect prescription. Hopefully, this answer provides you with enough information to devise your own experiments and find the solution that's right for your situation.